# How to click a menu item inside another menu item's menu, in applescript

Tags: ios, xcode6, applescript, xcode-instruments

To be more precise, how can you select a device from the 'Active devices' (from the devices pop up button) in Xcode's instruments.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKEQp.png)

Script:

```
tell application "Instruments"
click menu item "<Device name>" of menu 1 of menu item "Active Devices" of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of list 1 of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window "Instruments"
end tell
```

Comment: please refer to the image for better understanding of the question

Comment: I used the following script: <br/> tell application "Instruments" <br/> 
click menu item "*<Device name>*" of menu 1 of menu item "Active Devices" of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of list 1 of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window "Instruments" <br/> end tell

Comment: error:  Couldn't find the 'menu 1' of menu item "Active Devices" of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of list 1 of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window "Instruments"